# What is the different between UPrimitiveComponent's GetMass and CalculateMass?

Tags: unreal-engine4

In an udemy course I just went through a lecture where we needed to calculate the mass of some stuff.

I ended up using `CalculateMass`; but, the instructor used `GetMass`.

The [unreal documention for CalculateMass](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UPrimitiveComponent/CalculateMass/index.html) shows it accepts a parameter `FName BoneName`; but, I did not use this parameter and it still works. The documentation also talks about `CalculateMass` being potentially `~0.1` KiloGrams off the actual Mass; but, this looks like an insignificant amount.

What is the important difference between these 2 functions? When should one be used over the other?

Comment: Basically speed over accuracy. CalculateMass tends to be a little faster but less accurate as it doesn't read anything from the physics thread. And GetMass causes a readlock for that actor's physics simulation so it's slower but give's you the accurate number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**float CalculateMass(FName BoneName)**

Returns mass for the specified bone / body. In physics assets you can setup multiple physics bodies for a single mesh and get the mass separately. Hence the bone name parameter. It also returns with the overridden mass instead if it was specified. This is an assumed mass by the engine and may be a little different compared to GetMass. And it seems to be faster.

On the other hand...

**float GetMass() const**

Is pretty much similar for calling *CalculateMass(NAME_None);*

Except it returns the real mass of the body instance calculated by the physics engine.

To get the exact value it causes a thread lock on the physics engine to read the value.

So this is a little slower when executing.

I would use *CalculateMass* unless the exact mass must be precise.

Also caching the *CalculatedMass* in a variable if it's not changing frequently.

You can also dig into the engine code to better understand where these values come from ;)